# Why is the stock change calculated from the last day close instead of the current day open?

Tags: stocks, terminology, quotes

As I understand it, the stock change is intended to be a measure of how much the value of a stock changes over the course of a day. So why is it calculated as the difference between the current price and the *last day close*, instead of the difference between the current price and the *current day open*?

Comment: Some trading can still occur between the previous day's close-of-market and the current day's market-opening, so the two prices may not be the same.

Comment: In addition, price can gap up or gap down at the open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the stock change is intended to be a measure of how much the value of a stock changes over the course of a day.

No - it indicates the change from one day to the next (or more generally from one *period* to the next). Since the price can change from the end of one day to the beginning of the next day (due to after hours trading), you'd be missing the after-market changes if you only looked at intra-day change.